# Chrome Custom Tabs - Load text/String

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I would like to open a **Chrome Custom Tab**, not to launch a URL, but to display the contents of a `String`. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Opening a browser to be able to display a string is a bit too expensive, a cheaper alternative is to display it in the app itself, right?

Comment: If it's a relatively large string, but not crazy. Lets say 1000 words, I was hoping to be able to use an intent to send this data to inherit the great Search/Find functionality that chrome provides. Essentially for testers to view certain data in some scenarios and not a user facing feature.

Comment: ha, makes sense. You can send a "Data URI" via customtabs intent. I did not check, but it probably should work. This command worked for me: adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n com.android.chrome/.Main -d 'data:,Hello%2C%20World!'

Comment: there is a limit of how much you can encode into a single intent on Android, but I think 1000 words are within the limits